# How to zip a directory(PLSQL)

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have directory(D:\stuff) stuff,  i want to zip entire folder(stuff) with new name.

I can possible to do .BAT but i want to do  PLSQL procedure, function.

Please  help me on this.....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to produce a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); aside from this, be sure to show us what you've tried; what the issue is, what behavior is expected, etc.

Comment: A quick google search shows a bunch of useful results.